# Change binding of listbox after defining one

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Listbox and I binded it an action but the thing is if there is no result to show(empty listbox), that binding still works. So for those cases I need to update that binding.

This is my list

```
lst = tk.Listbox(self.frm2, selectmode="SINGLE", width="40", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
lst.bind("<Double-Button-1>", open_folder)
lst.pack(fill="both")
```

For a button, I know, I can change its options by something like this even after packing it.

```
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="button", command=do_smth)
btn1.pack()

btn1["state"] = "disabled"
```

So I tried this, but it's not working.

```
lst["bind"] = ("<<ListboxSelect>>", do_nothing) 
 _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bind"
```

Comment: Why unbind it? Why not just have your `open_folder` simply not do anything if nothing is selected? You get the same effect with less complexity that continually switching bindings in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unbind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.unbind-method) method:

```
lst.unbind("<Double-Button-1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to convert [Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322991/change-binding-of-listbox-after-defining-one#comment35710792_23322991) into an answer since it *probably* is better way to do this than switching bindings.

```
def open_folder(event):
    if event.widget.curselection():
        #do your things if anything is selected
```